# AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled, and i dont have gpu what i do now?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

Hi i want to run this https://github.com/zhengyima/DeepNude_NoWatermark_withModel/archive/master.zip
and when i run main.py
it gave me assertionerror
this is log:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\dn>python main.py
Processing input.png
Executing phase: dress_to_correct
Executing phase: correct_to_mask
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 58, in <module>
    main(inputpath, outputpath, show)
  File "main.py", line 37, in main
    watermark = deep_nude_process(inputpath)
  File "main.py", line 48, in deep_nude_process
    watermark = process(dress)
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\dn\run.py", line 115, in process
    model.initialize(opt)
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\dn\gan.py", line 66, in initialize
    self.netG = self.__define_G(opt.input_nc, opt.output_nc, opt.ngf, opt.netG,
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\dn\gan.py", line 117, in __define_G
    netG.cuda(gpu_ids[0])
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 906, in cuda
    return self._apply(lambda t: t.cuda(device))
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 798, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 798, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 821, in _apply
    param_applied = fn(param)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 906, in <lambda>
    return self._apply(lambda t: t.cuda(device))
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\cuda\__init__.py", line 239, in _lazy_init
    raise AssertionError("Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled")
AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled
```

I dont have gpu and i cant download cuda.
what i do now?

i did almost every solution on internet.

Comment: change your script so it doesn't ask for cuda?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.